# Remove ? from query string swift 4

Tags: swift, nsurlcomponents

I have a url in which I add URL components to it to form a query string. For example the url is `https://example.com/test`, and with the url components the final url is `https://example.com/test?urlcomponent1=1&urlcomponent2=1234`.

I need to keep the final url with the urlcomponents, but I need to remove the ?. How do I do that? So the final url would be `https://example.com/testurlcomponent1=1&urlcomponent2=1234`.

I have looked into removing artifacts, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: Curious why you would want to remove the `?` since it makes it an invalid URL.

Comment: For some reason the server I communicate with doesn't like the ?. I know it doesn't make sense, but that is how someone set it up. The ? actually causes an empty response.

Comment: Sounds like there is either an issue with how you call the server or a problem with how the server handles the URL. Which ever it is should be fixed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you only have one ? in your url, you can remove it using replacingOccurrencesOf

```
let newURL = URL(string: url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "?", with: ""))
```

Comment: I imagine there would only be one '?'. Can you even have multiple ?s in a valid URL

Comment: I actually did the replacingOccurrences, but put it in the wrong location. This works of course when you add it to the correct url. Thanks.